# preg_replace_callback replaces just first occurrence

Tags: php, regex

I have the regex to find all numbers with percentage (100|\d\d|\d)\% - this regex is given and I am not allowed to change it. I have input string:

```
Lorem ipsum 10% dolor, 8%sit amet 50%
```

I need then to highligh (with HTML tags) parts of string according to that regex so I'd get

```
Lorem ipsum <i>10%</i> dolor, <i>8%</i>sit amet <i>50%</i>
```

Because preg_replace would work only with regex like (100%|\d\d%|\d%) otherwise it would highlight only numbers 0-100. I am using preg_replace_callback like this:

```
<?php
    $string = "Lorem ipsum 10% dolor, 8%sit amet 50%";
      $count = 0;
        function foo($matches){
            global $count;
            return "<i>".$matches[$count++]."</i>";

        }
        $reg = "/(100|\d\d|\d)\%/";
        $str_out = preg_replace_callback($reg, "foo", $string, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
?>
```

The output is this though:

```
Lorem ipsum <i>10%</i> dolor, 8%sit amet 50%
```

Only first occurence is replaced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `preg_replace` also:

```
$reg = '/(100|\d\d|\d)%/';
$repl = preg_replace( $reg, '<i>$0</i>', $input);
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mF7uU4/4)

Comment: This would be too easy. As I said, I can't change the regex, unfortunately, so I need to work with what I have. The thing is that initially there would be a whole file full of regular expressions. I'd take them one by one, check them and use them so the procedure has to be automatic and work in general.

Comment: [Even your regex will work here with preg_replace](https://regex101.com/r/mF7uU4/2)

Comment: That's true, but it took away the "%" which I need to highlight as well. My regex with preg_replace will highlight only numbers 0-100 as I said above.

Comment: I would have to check if regex searches for percentage and then add it to string, which would be complicated. And the regex itself is a variable. I aim to make it work for general-purpose not just for one particular regex. It's just this one would not pass the tests.

Comment: Since your regex is already searching for `%` `$reg = "/(100|\d\d|\d)\%/";` you can just use replacement as `<i>$0</i>` [Check this demo](https://regex101.com/r/mF7uU4/4)

Comment: That works just right. Thanks a lot @anubhava. This whole string thing never cease to amaze me.

Comment: ok great, I have updated the answer with the solution that worked for you. If you're satisfied you may accept the answer.